# sort occurrence matrix to minimize its spatial variance

Tags: variance

Is there any algorithm or an approach that sort occurrence matrix to reduce its spatial variance. I mean by spatial variance moving window variance (n*n moving box).

Comment: I wished to add tags [matrix sort spatial variance], but me not yet allowed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone got the same concern, https://gmarti.gitlab.io/ml/2017/09/07/how-to-sort-distance-matrix.html